# What is the meaning of 'be set to' in this sentence?

Tags: vocabulary

In the following sentence, what is the meaning of 'be set to'? I think it has the meaning of 'to be ready/prepared to'. If not so, I'd like to know the other meaning of it.

> Many electric clocks are combined with radios, which can sometimes be set to turn on automatically.

Comment: Think of "set" meaning setting a time on the clock for when the radio should come on.

Answer (score 1):

Merriam-Webster gives the following [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/set):

> to adjust (a device and especially a measuring device) to a desired position

*Setting* devices such as a radio or clock generally involves pressing buttons or turning dials to change certain aspects of the device, such as what time the clock shows, what time the radio turns on, or what station the radio should play.

Answer (score 0):

Think about, for example, your cell phone. It has a "**settings**" menu where you can adjust,add, or remove certain functionalities like location services, ringtone, volume, or the size of the font. You can **change settings**, like changing the setting from normal to night mode. Notice that a setting is a noun in this usage.

We can turn this into verb form:

> I **set** my phone to vibrate on silent. I **set** my alarm to go off at 6AM.

A good synonym here is "programmed":

> Many electric clocks are combined with radios, which can sometimes be **programmed** to turn on automatically.